# python print() crash script when it's detached from console & console closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, background, stdout, detach

I have a python3 script which I run from console.
When I try to run it detached from console using

> 1. script.py & disown -f
> 2. setsid -f script.py

then I close the console, the script crash after a while.

If I detach it using:

> 3. nohup script.py &
> 4. at now
>    script.py
>    Ctrl+D

it keeps running.

Script sleep, wake up every 10s do Some processing, print some output.
I discovered the script is crashing because of `print()`.
When I comment out the lines with `print()`, it run without problems
when I detached it from console and console is closed.

I solved this by using logging module:
`logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.INFO,handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)])`
and replace `print()` with `logging.info()`

So, stdout is "closed"/"invalid" when the script is detached from console
using first 3 methods then console is closed.  I  knew that but I did not know will affect python, bash script don't care about it.
4th method does not close stdout, the output is sent on mail, so that's why it works.

***I am curious how can I check in this situation if it is safe to write to stdout, using `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()` ?***

I tried both of these conditions

```
if sys.stdout.closed==False 
if sys.stdout is not None
```

but print() is still called when the script is detached from console using above first 2 methods, then console is closed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import sys

for i in range(1,100):
    # same result
    #if sys.stdout.closed==False
    if sys.stdout  is not None 
        print(str(i))
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.stdout.writable` return true when script.py is detached from terminal using 1. and 2. and calling `print(`) crash the script.

But I found that I can check if script is still connected to tty with:

```
if sys.stdout.isatty() :
    print(...)
```

this works to avoid `print()` when script is detached from tty.